# Why spring-roo generated integrationtest did not update my tables

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, spring-roo

I am new to Spring-roo, I followed the 10 minutes tutorial, and try testing the example.  I use PostgreSQL as my database, and I can create tables after running the generated integration test, but I don't understand why there is nothing have been written to those table during the test.  I see the hibernate_sequence has been changed after every test, I'm sure the connection is OK, I just don't know what kind of magic spring has done to stop the tests from updating the tables, which could be a good thing for testing, but I just don't understand which snippet do the magic.

```
@Test
public void testPersist() {
    Assert.assertNotNull("Data on demand for 'Credential' failed to initialize correctly", dod.getRandomCredential());
    Credential obj = dod.getNewTransientCredential(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    Assert.assertNotNull("Data on demand for 'Credential' failed to provide a new transient entity", obj);
    Assert.assertNull("Expected 'Credential' identifier to be null", obj.getId());
    try {
        obj.persist();
    } catch (final ConstraintViolationException e) {
        final StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
        for (Iterator<ConstraintViolation<?>> iter = e.getConstraintViolations().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            final ConstraintViolation<?> cv = iter.next();
            msg.append("[").append(cv.getRootBean().getClass().getName()).append(".").append(cv.getPropertyPath()).append(": ").append(cv.getMessage()).append(" (invalid value = ").append(cv.getInvalidValue()).append(")").append("]");
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException(msg.toString(), e);
    }
    obj.flush();
    Assert.assertNotNull("Expected 'Credential' identifier to no longer be null", obj.getId());
}
```

I see the obj being flush, but nothing has been found in the table, please help.

Comment: Spring sets the transaction to rollback in test mode. This means that the transaction is always rolled back rather than committed so that you can run multiple integration tests without them interfering with each-other.

Comment: Thanks, and do you know how can I turn it off?

Comment: Either `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)` at the class level or `@Rollback(false)` for a test method. Why on earth would you want to though?

Comment: Thanks, because I'm new to spring and IOC, just wanted to know how it works.